# Why does my rails update method using the same strong params as my create method, give me an argument error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, argument-error

I am using Rails 5.2 and building an ecomm site.

My `new.html.erb` page has a simple_form with a combination of `Product` fields as well as other params which are handled outside the strong params and the creation of the new instance.

One of the features of the form is a `eventListener` which creates the `:sku` automatically based on four input values. The product number, the sku and the live status are hidden.

Here is the simplified version of the `html.erb`:

```
<%= simple_form_for @new_product do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>

  <%= f.input :name%>

  <%= f.association :size, collection: @all_sizes.map{ |s| [s.name, s.id, {'data-code-num' => s.code_num}]}, input_html:{class: 'sku-suffix-component'} %>
  <%= f.association :color, collection: @all_colors.map{ |s| [s.name, s.id, {'data-code-num' => s.code_num}]}, input_html:{class: 'sku-suffix-component'} %>
  <%= f.association :pattern, collection: @all_patterns.map{ |s| [s.name, s.id, {'data-code-num' => s.code_num}]}, input_html:{class: 'sku-suffix-component'} %>
  <%= f.input :product_number, as: :hidden, input_html:{ value: @new_product.product_number, class: "sku-suffix-component" } %>
  <%= f.input :sku,as: :hidden, html:{id: "new-product-form-sku-input"} %>

  <%= f.input :live_status, as: :hidden, :input_html => { :value => @new_product.live_status } %>
  <%= f.input :description, as: :text %>
  <%= f.association :brand%>
  <%= f.association :style %>
  <%= f.input :price %>
  <%= f.input :quantity, input_html:{value: 1}%>
  <%= f.association :segment %>
  <%= f.association :main_category %>
  <%= f.association :category %>
  <%= f.association :country, class: '' %>

  <!-- Here are some inputs for adding records to a material join table -->
  <!-- And the names of the inputs are dynamically created -->
  <% 5.times.with_index do |_, i| %>
    <% num = i + 1 %>
    <label class="form-control-label integer" for="material_percent_id_<%= num < 10 ? "0" + num.to_s : num.to_s %>">Percent</label>
    <input class="form-control numeric integer required" type="number" step="1" name="material_percent_<%= num < 10 ? "0" + num.to_s : num.to_s %>" id="material_percent_id_<%= num < 10 ? "0" + num.to_s : num.to_s %>">

    <label class="form-control-label select" for="material_id_id_<%= num < 10 ? "0" + num.to_s : num.to_s %>">Material Component #<%= num %> </label>
    <select class="form-control select" name="material_id_<%= num < 10 ? "0" + num.to_s : num.to_s %>" id="material_id_id_<%= num < 10 ? "0" + num.to_s : num.to_s %>">
      <option value=""></option>
      <% @all_materials.each do |material| %>
        <option value="<%= material.id %>"><%= material.name %></option>
      <% end %>
    </select>
  <% end %>

  <!-- Here are some inputs for adding multiple photos to the products using active_storage -->
  <% (1..8).each do |i| %>
      <%= f.label "Photo [#{i}]"  %>
      <%= f.file_field :photos, multiple: true %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.button :submit %>

<% end %>
```

Creating new products using this `simple_form` works fine, along with instances in the join table, through the `create method`, shown here:

```
def create
  @all_sizes = Size.all
  @all_colors = Color.all
  @all_patterns = Pattern.all
  @new_product = Product.new(product_params)
  @all_materials = Material.all

  if @new_product.save
    5.times.with_index do |_, i|
      if params["material_id_0#{(i + 1)}"] != ""
        ProductMaterial.create!(product_id: @new_product.id,
                                material_id: params["material_id_0#{(i + 1)}"].to_i,
                                percent: params["material_percent_0#{(i + 1)}"].to_i)
      else
        break
      end
    end
    redirect_to @new_product
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Using nearly the exact same form (some code added to dynamically render the join table inputs and the photos inputs correctly), but all inputs present; and using the exact same strong params in the controller; going through the `update` method in the controller produces an argument error. Here is the `update` method:

```
  def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])

    @product = Product.update(product_params) # here is where the error happens
    @all_sizes = Size.all
    @all_colors = Color.all
    @all_patterns = Pattern.all
    @all_materials = Material.all

    if @product.save
      5.times.with_index do |_, i|
        if params["material_id_0#{(i + 1)}"] != ""
          ProductMaterial.create!(product_id: @product.id,
                                  material_id: params["material_id_0#{(i + 1)}"].to_i,
                                  percent: params["material_percent_0#{(i + 1)}"].to_i)
        else
          break
        end
      end
      redirect_to @product
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

Here is the exact syntax of the error as seen in the server:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)):

app/controllers/products_controller.rb:72:in `update'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
@product = Product.update(product_params)
```

you're trying to call instance method `update` on the Product class itself. `new` is a class method, so it works good in create action. How it should be:

```
def update
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  # here you define different @all instances

  # you don't need to update and save separately, because instance is saved already 
  # if you call update on it and update goes well
  if @product.update(product_params) 
    # here goes the rest controller code
```

Comment: Thanks - probably at the exact same time you answered - I repeatedly smashed my head against the keyboard, because I saw it too. difference is that it took you minutes to find that error, and I've been stuck for days! Many thanks!